# Failed to create Oracle Text Index

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-text

I want to create an text index for a single column for a table using this command:

```
CREATE INDEX    product_fulltext_index 
ON              products( computed_name )
INDEXTYPE IS    ctxsys.context
```

I tried to search but I have not found the solution yet, maybe the error message is too vague

[image]

This is my table design:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error **screenshot** suggests that you're trying to create index on `name` column. **Text** of your question says that column name is `computed_name`. So, which one of them is it, really?

Anyway: if it is on

```
name Nvarchar2(500)
     ^
     |
```

then you can't do what you want because you can't create Oracle Text index on a column whose datatype uses the National Character set (**N**VARCHAR2). Why not? Because Oracle doesn't support it.

Either change column's datatype to e.g. `VARCHAR2`, or accept the fact that you can't have what you wanted.